# Txn version not supported Polkadot/Acala bridge!

Tags: acala

I successfully confirmed the transfer of `DOTs` to `Acala` using Ledger. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to validate withdrawals or staking. Both Polkadot and Ledger have been updated to their latest versions, and `Acala` is properly installed on the Ledger device. Here's the error message I'm receiving:
[https://apps.acala.network/ldot]
chain   Acala
version 2180
nonce   0
method
xTokens.transfer(currencyId, amount, dest, destWeightLimit)
info
lifetime    mortal, valid from 4,353,611 to 4,353,643
Txn version not supported